# enable and disable a button Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a way to disable a `Button`. This is an app I made that is an egg timer, and I run into one bug; when I press the play button multiple times the timer speeds up and I can't get it to stop. I want to create a disable feature, but everything I've seen on the forum says to use. `enable = true`. When I use this Xcode says that it isn't valid. What is the proper code for enabling and disabling a button in Xcode 8?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = Timer()
    var myCount = 210
    var button = 0

    func processTimer() {

        //what happens every second

        counter()

    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.processTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        button = 1
    }

    func pauseTimer() {
        timer.invalidate()
        button = 0
    }

    func resetTimer(){
        timer.invalidate()
        myCount = 210
        countdown.text = "\(myCount)"
        button = 0
    }

    func counter() {
        myCount -= 1
        if myCount > 0 {
            countdown.text = "\(myCount)"
        } else {
            countdown.text = "0"
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

    func add(){
        myCount += 10
        if myCount > 0 {
            countdown.text = "\(myCount)"
        } else {
            countdown.text = "0"
        }
    }

    func sub(){
        myCount -= 10
        if myCount > 0 {
            countdown.text = "\(myCount)"
        } else {
            countdown.text = "0"
        }
    }






    // timer countdown
    @IBOutlet var countdown: UILabel!

    // pause button
    @IBAction func pauseButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        pauseTimer()
        print("Timer Paused")
    }


    //play button
    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        startTimer()
        print("Timer started")
    }


    // -10 seconds
    @IBAction func minusTen(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        sub()



    }
    // reset timer to 290
    @IBAction func resetButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        resetTimer()
        print("Timer Reset")
    }






    // +10 seconds
    @IBAction func addTen(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        add()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        countdown.text = "\(myCount)"

        if button == 0{
            playButton.enabled = true
        }




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: `enabled` -> `isEnabled`

Answer (score 3):

There is two ways to `enabled/disable` the `Button`.

```
playButton.isEnabled = false // This will give the (style) effect of disable to button
```

or

```
playButton.userInteractionEnabled = false // This will not give the (style) effect of disable
                                         to button simply stop the user interaction
```

Comment: can you give detail about error that you are getting.

Comment: With that I get the error, "Value of type '(AnyObject) -> ()' has no member "userInteractionEnabled'"

Comment: sorry I am new to this website, I didn't mean to post the previous comment without the error information

Comment: In your case button is `playButton`, check the edited answer.

Comment: @ColtonCarnevale you need to set the `isEnabled` on an IBOutlet, not IBAction.

Comment: @ColtonCarnevale If you using `isEnabled` inside IBAction, you need to convert first `AnyObject` to `UIButton` like this `(sender as! UIButton).isEnabled = false`

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to do is add an outlet for your button.  You have created the function, but you need a separate outlet if you want to make changes - something like this

```
    @IBOutlet weak var cmdPlayButton: UIButton!
```

then, if you want to prevent multiple presses on the button while the timer is running, you need to disable the button as soon as it is pressed, and only re-enable it when the timer finishes

```
//play button
@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    cmdPlayButton.enabled = false
    startTimer()
    print("Timer started")
}
```

just remember to enable the button when the timer finishes or is reset, and you will need to handle the pause functionality - you might change the text on the play button to read 'restart' for instance.